# Convert DAX expression table into a scalar

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to convert the following DAX expression to a scalar?

```
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(rules, rules[RuleNumber] = 1), "AntecedentID", [AntecedentID])
```

This returns a table with a single cell, but I need a scalar value.

Tried wrapping the expression into a `VALUES` or a `MAX`, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
M =
CONCATENATEX (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER ( rules, rules[RuleNumber] = 1 ),
        "@AntecedentID", [AntecedentID]
    ),
    [@AntecedentID],
    ", "
)
```